# How to search header file and create missing directory in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu

In my project i have directory structure `/libs` and `/src`. I want to create `makefile` where `main` has dependency in `/libs`. ie. header file is in the `/libs`. I have used the following

```
#Compiler to use
CC=gcc
#Compiler flags to use
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

BUILD = ./build
SRC = ./src
LIBS = ./libs

SOURCES = $(SRC)/main.c $(SRC)/SmallComponent1.c $(SRC)/SmallComponent2.c $(LIBS)/ExtLib.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES: .c=.o)
EXECUTABLE = $(BUILD)/appl.exe
all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(BUILD):
    mkdir $(BUILD)

$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ 
.c.o: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(LIBS) $< -o $@





phony: clean
clean:
    rm $(BUILD)/*.o $(BUILD)/appl.exe
```

Questions are: how can i create `/build` if not exist? and how to include external `.h` in the `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(LIBS) $< -o $@`, because `-I$(LIBS)`
does not work and i got following error `./src/main.c:4:20: fatal error: ExtLib.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. What version of Make are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the build directory before it is needed use an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) (OOP) and use the `-p` option of `mkdir` to avoid getting an error if it exists already (it should not be needed because of the OOP but it is always better to use this option in Makefiles):

```
$(BUILD):
    mkdir -p $@

$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJECTS) | $(BUILD)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

For your other problem we need some more information; as you describe it it is not reproducible. Try maybe to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help